# How to exclude specific keys from Array.push()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble excluding items from an `Array.push()`, I've got something that seems to work, but worry for performance reasons that this may not be the best way to do it:

```
this.iframe_settings = (localStorage.getItem('iframe_settings') != null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iframe_settings')) : null


var _i = this,
    iframeSource = []

const isAffIdSet = (_i.iframe_settings && _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] != '' && _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] != null) ? true : false
const isSubIdSet = (_i.iframe_settings && _i.iframe_settings['sub_id'] != '' && _i.iframe_settings['sub_id'] != null) ? true : false

Object.keys(this.iframe_settings).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key != 'target') {

    if (key == 'sub_id') {
      if (isAffIdSet && !isSubIdSet) {
        _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] = _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id']
      } else if (isAffIdSet && isSubIdSet) {
        _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] = `${_i.iframe_settings['cpm_id']}|flex_repay,${_i.iframe_settings['sub_id']}`
      } else if (isAffIdSet && !isSubIdSet) {
        _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] = _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id']
      } else {
        _i.iframe_settings['cpm_id'] = 'flex_repay'
      }
    }

    iframeSource.push(`&${key}=${_i.iframe_settings[key]}`);
  }
});
```

My code saves an object to `iframe_settings`, which is `null` by default. I'd to exclude `&target=X` from the list of keys retrieved?

Comment: Why is this duplicated?: `if (isAffIdSet && !isSubIdSet) {...} . . . else if (isAffIdSet && !isSubIdSet) {...)`

Comment: That's my mistake, but isn't the question I've asked :)

Comment: A `for` loop could be faster than `forEach`...depends on the number of elements. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS). Hope this helps...somewhat :)

Comment: Your title is not clear. You're asking about performance, but you're not mentioned it in your title.